# Zoom control to WPF Form

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

How can I implement a zoom control to my wpf forms similar to the one avaialble in the visual studio designer?

thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Put your stuff into a grid, bind the grid's scale render transformation to a slider (slider should have min value of 1):

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.867*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.133*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="1"/>
        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform 
                    ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider}" 
                    ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TextBox Text="TextBox" Height="45.214"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="194,139,209,0"/>
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
Text="TextBox" Margin="194,0,209,118.254" Height="48.96"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You may want to use `LayoutTransform` for zooming, this will alow any parent `ScrollViewer` controls to show scroll bars correctly.

Comment: @Brett: Thanks!  Your comment answered my related question perfectly!

Comment: minor point but all FramewrokElements have Render/LayoutTransform so the grid is not a necessary element here

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could try out the Zoom Control which is part of [WPF Extensions available on Codeplex](http://wpfextensions.codeplex.com):

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfextensions&DownloadId=66810](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfextensions&DownloadId=66810)

Comment: After fighting with this control for some time, I decided not to use it, seems to have bugs when placing the control (doesn't get centered).

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/mitsu/archive/2009/03/09/wpf-surface-demo-driving-an-extending-desktop-with-a-popfly-duck.aspx) by Mitsu Furuta (don't worry about the funny title !). I'm not sure whether it meets your requirements exactly, but it could give you some ideas...

Answer (score 1):

To get a professional Zoom Control for WPF check out the [ZoomPanel](http://www.wpf-graphics.com/ZoomPanel.aspx).

It is not free, but is very easy to use and has many features - animated zooming and panning, support for ScrollViewer, mouse wheel support, included ZoomController (with move, zoom in, zoom out, rectangle zoom, reset buttons). It also comes with many code samples.