# Dynamically update Font Size of application with a single trigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, fonts

I have an application which has different font sizes for different controls say Button: 10, TextBlock : 12 etc.
I want to give options to the user where he can select any one of the below say
Normal , Small, Big, Bigger.

Suppose one selects "small" I would want to decrease every distinct font size by 2.
If "Big", I would want to increase every font size by 2. 
I hope we can do this using converter sending actual font size as parameter and render as per the selected choice if I am not wrong.
What will be the best option. Sorry if my doubt is absurd or silly. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind scaling graphics as well as text, you can use a transform to scale the content for the main portion of your app as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850554/zoom-control-to-wpf-form). If you have a status bar in your app, that might be a good place for the zoom slider.