# Winforms and contents to run on any resolution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a problem with getting my content in a WinForm application to properly resize to fit any screen resolution, How can I solve this?

I used

```
this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

The size of the form was successfully changed according to the computer's resolution but the contents were not.

Comment: Have you docked all your controls?

Comment: Yes..if docked correctly, the controls will resize to fit the forms size

Comment: Anchor or Dock them it will help.

Answer (score 5):

The controls inside of a WinForms form do not change based on the size of the form. Textboxes, radio buttons, etc are based on a specific pixel size and do not vary by resolution.

You have to develop your form to work with different resolutions. You will want to use lots of panels with the DockStyle set appropriately. You can hide panels that won't fit (though you might need to provide an alternate way to get to them).

If you need it to change based on resolution, you might want to look into WPF.

Comment: On Wpf it goes the same with WinForms. The difference is that dock properties are easy to use at wpf.

Comment: I don't really know XAML, but as I understand it, you can add scale transforms that will allow you to change the size of a control. Here's a SO question that asks about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850554/zoom-control-to-wpf-form

Answer (score 3):

For winforms [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties can help you on this. But they are not powerful as new WPF features (Eg: [viewBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/resize_form.aspx)). Containers like SplitContainer and Panels can be resized properly with the Dock property. But there is no easy+nice ways to resize child controls like buttons, labels. Those child controls are also support for Dock/Anchor properties though.

Below are some useful articles for your reference.

[Article 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/anchordock.aspx)

[Article 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/resize_form.aspx)